# Adding a overbar/overline on a single letter or obtaining "x bar"?

Tags: google-docs

Using Google Docs, I need an X with a line on top, the equivalent to latex `\bar{x}` and what statisticians call "x bar". I was using an equation field and `\overline` but it adds the line over the entire equation. Is there a way to do this?

## x̄

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the "math operations" button on the equation bar, there's the symbol you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Or... you can search for "x bar" in Google and do a copy/paste from one of the web pages that come up.  It looks a lot better than the x bar in Google Docs: x̄

Answer (score 1):

The answer is just to press <kbd>enter</kbd> after you are finished writing characters with the overline, and it will toggle it off.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by going to `Insert Menu` > `Special Characters` > then search `overline`.

A very late answer but I hope this helps someone later.

Comment: Definitely helped, thank you!